# In Adventurers League, when a Weapon of Warning is found, is just that particular weapon unlocked? Or is Weapon of Warning unlocked in general?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, weapons, dnd-adventurers-league

Suppose I am playing an AL game wherein the party obtains a *trident of warning*. Is only the *trident of warning* unlocked? Or is *weapon of warning* unlocked in general?

Same question could apply to *vicious weapon*, and probably others as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only found one relevant quote (but I would think there is more buried in other documents):

From Detect Thoughts v1.3 (from the [Adventure League website](http://dndadventurersleague.org/)):

> *Older adventures sometimes include magic items with additional quirks, such as the wolfskin cap (Hat of Disguise) from a Season 4 adventure. Upon completion of the adventure, do characters unlock the item with quirks or without?*
>
> **Items are unlocked specifically as they are found in the adventure.**

In this case it is referring to an item that has additional properties or a unique description (such as details found on certificates). But the message is the same, your character unlocks the exact same item as they found. So if you found a [Ring of Cold Resistance](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-resistance), it stays a Ring of Cold Resistance. Even though the "base" item allows different types of resistance, you can't switch it out.

So in your case, you found a [Weapon of Warning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/weapon-of-warning), it is in the form of a trident and cannot be changed.